Asking hiring manager what work will be done with a required software?
I work as a software developer at a consulting company, and we're always moving to different projects within the company.
In my case, I applied to another project which looked interesting. The group is interested in my resume, but they need someone with experience in guidewire. I briefly used the software long ago, but I can't say I have experience with it.
Since the requirement only says that I need to have experience with Guidewire, how can I ask the hiring contact what type of work needs to be done with the software?
If it's simple enough I can take fresher courses on Guidewire and complete the tasks. On the other hand, if the work with Guidewire is complex, then I would not be a good match.

I'd advise, since you have very limited expertise with the said tool/framework/software, rather than you trying to evaluate the level of complexity of the work involved, let the hiring manager/team evaluate the level of proficiency you have with the tool. Since they are the ones having more insight on the project and related work, they'd be a better judge of the required and available skill.
When you are going to have a discussion with the new team or manager for the opportunity, mention what you have mentioned here, and let them decide whether they want to go ahead with that level of proficiency (and allow you to train and upskill - internally or externally) or not (they need someone with more expertise to start with).
Either way, the bottom line is: talk to them clearly.
